Draining, or Disabling workers with request.get
I am using Apache2.4 on windows. The system is not cloud-based. I need to change the status of workers using Python, such as setting them to drain, disable, or enable. Although my code runs without errors, the worker statuses are not being updated in either the load balancer manager page or the services window.This is my code:
[enter image description here][1]
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
html = response.text
    # Define the base URL for the balancer manager
    base_url = "https://x.com/balancer-manager"

    # Extracted parameters from the provided HTML
    balancer = "mybalancerName"
    worker =  "https://x.com:8443//Invoke"

    nonce = "wbfcb4f6-fe6b-104f-35d3-945c1d756443"#I have copied the nonce number from html response

    # Construct the URL to change the worker's status to "Init Drn Ok"
    url = "{}?b={}&w={}&nonce={}&dw=drain".format(base_url, balancer, worker, nonce)

    # Sending the GET request to change the status without any headers
    response = requests.get(url, verify=True)
    
    # Check the response
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Worker status changed to 'Init Drn Ok' successfully.")
    else:
        print("Failed to change status. HTTP status code: ")
        print(response.text)

